# Laravel-echo-server нет подключение клиента к серверу

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Пытаюсь подключить `laravel-echo-server`

```
{
  "authHost": "http://want_can.lc",
  "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
  "clients": [],
  "database": "redis",
  "databaseConfig": {
    "redis": {
            "port": 6379,
            "host":"127.0.0.1",
            "keyPrefix":null
        },
    "sqlite": {
      "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
    }
  },
  "devMode": true,
  "host": null,
  "port": "6001",
  "protocol": "http",
  "socketio": {},
  "secureOptions": 67108864,
  "sslCertPath": "",
  "sslKeyPath": "",
  "sslCertChainPath": "",
  "sslPassphrase": "",
  "subscribers": {
    "http": true,
    "redis": true
  },
  "apiOriginAllow": {
    "allowCors": false,
    "allowOrigin": "",
    "allowMethods": "",
    "allowHeaders": ""
  }
}
```

вот bootstrap

```
if (typeof io !== 'undefined') {
window.Echo = new Echo({
     broadcaster: 'socket.io',
     host:window.location.hostname +":"+ '6001',
 });
}else{
    console.log('AAA!')
}
```

вот событие

```
namespace App\Events;


class PrivateChat implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $data;
    public $user;

    public function __construct($data,User $user)
    {

        $this->data=$data;
        $this->user=$user;
        $this->dontBroadcastToCurrentUser();
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        Message::create($this->data,$this->user);
        return new PrivateChannel('room.'.$this->data['room_id']);
    }
}
```

вот контролер

```
class MessageController
{
    public $service;

    public function __construct(ChatroomService $service)
    {
        $this->service=$service;
    }

    public function message(ChatRequest $request,User $user)
    {
        event ( new PrivateChat($request->all(), $user));
    }
}
```

вот каналы

```
Broadcast::channel('room.{room_id}', function ( $user, $room_id) {
    return $user->chatroomsCustomer->contains($room_id)||$user->chatroomsExecutor->contains($room_id);
});
```

настройки `key-perfix` для `redis` в `config/database.php`

```
'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'redis'),
            'prefix' => null,
        ],
```

вот так во vue.js

```
    methods:{
        update:function (id) {
            axios.post('chatroom',{
            room_id:id
            }).then((response)=>{
                this.message=response.data;
            });

            window.Echo
            .private('room'+{id})
            .listen('PrivateChat',
                ({data})=>{
                    console.log(data)
                    this.message.messages.push(data.body)
                })
        },
```

запускаю `laravel-echo-server`
запускаю очередь захожу на страницу отрываю консоль вкладка network
вижу
https://prnt.sc/xyunid
т.е. сокет не получает sid.
в socket-echo-server если пользователь набирает сообщение в терминале получаем

```
Channel: private-room.1
Event: App\Events\PrivateChat
```

вот что получаю в очереди

```
[2021-02-01 06:50:25][RXvfnlILeDt6J2MTWAXPA9EStl1Cgi5X] Processing: App\Events\PrivateChat
[2021-02-01 06:50:25][RXvfnlILeDt6J2MTWAXPA9EStl1Cgi5X] Processed:  App\Events\PrivateChat
```

поставил [приблуду](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/laravel-echo-client/hkkmakkbaokmfhpcahpdjlmnmndfdlal) она подключается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в версии сокетов. Они уже третьей версии а laravel-echo-server ни кто не переделывал пока.

Answer (score 0):

1. Допускаю, что вы умышленно убрали код авторизации в примере. Если нет, то вам необходимо добавить токен юзера в параметры подключения.
2. По умолчанию laravel добавляет неймспейс к названию ивента, то есть на фронте ивент будет называться `App.Events.PrivateChat`. Здесь у вас есть 2 варианта:

   1. Слушать ивент App.Events.PrivateChat. `.listen('App.Events.PrivateChat')`
   2. Добавить namespace в опцию Echo `namespace: 'App.Events'`. Слушать ивент PrivateChat. `.listen('PrivateChat')`.
3. Заметил, что вы используете цепочку `.channel('room').private('PrivateChat')`. `private()` и `channel()` методы подключения к каналам (публичному и приватному соответственно), и не должны вызываться друг за другом. В `channel()` вы передаете название канала `room`, а в `private()` передаете название ивента. Во-первых, названия ваших каналов имеют вид `room.{id}`, а не просто `room`, в-вторых, вы подключаетесь к приватному каналу, поэтому должны использовать метод `private()` вместо `channel()`, во-третьих `PrivateChat` это название ивента, который мы должны слушать, правильной цепочкой в данном случае будет: `window.Echo.private('room.1').listen('PrivateChat',`

В конечном итоге подключение к серверу должно выглядеть примерно так:

```
new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: window.location.hostname + ':' + '6001',
    namespace: 'App.Events',
    auth: {
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
        }
    }
});
```

А подключение к каналу и прослушивание ивентов так:

```
window.Echo
    .private('room.1') //room с id=1
    .listen('PrivateChat', (data) => {
        console.log(data)
    });
```

Comment: 1. у меня статичное приложение авторизация орагинзована через auth вот так https://laravel.su/docs/6.x/authentication  я ни где не встречал в документации необходимость в авторизации
можете дать ссылку на документацию где это указано ? 
2. про namespace вроде в документации написано что по умолчанию используется  App.Event вот https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/broadcasting#namespaces   
3 channel или private  это были попытки попытки использовать то один каналы  то другие абы заработало это оставшийся артифакт перезда  спасибо что сказали сейчас уберу из вопроса.

Comment: @Sergalas вы в канале используете юзера, следовательно подразумевается, что пользователь авторизован. Взаимодействие происходит так: фронт отправляет запрос авторизации с апи токеном юзера на экхо сервер, экхо сервер отправляет запрос авторизации в ваше приложение по указанным вами json конфиге broadcasting серверу и путю, дальше вы подключены и можете обмениваться данными. Так как echo server авторизовывается сам, то он не имеет никакого понятия о сессии пользователя, используемой в Auth имплентации ларавеля.

Comment: @Sergalas для использования авторизации по токену в BroadcastServiceProvider.php вместо  `Broadcast::routes()` должно быть `Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => 'auth:api']])`. В таблице users должны быть колонка api_token со сгенерированным ключами, которые вы и передает в опцию Authorization.

Comment: @Sergalas по второму пункту как раз таки в доке про это ничего не сказано, и описание весьма расплывчатое.

Comment: а разве настройка "authHost": "http://want_can" как раз не отвечает за авторизацию ?